# What does Vagrant file structure look like?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, vagrantfile

Is this file structure correct for using Vagrant?

I have 1 Vagrantfile in a work folder that contains all my projects.

Is this how you use Vagrant?

1 Vagrant file and 1 virtual machine that runs all the projects in same work folder.

Folder structure

```
work/
└── Vagrantfile/
    ├── project1
    │   └── project1root
    ├── project2
    │   └── project2root
    └── project3
        └── project3root
```

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant is a tool. Tools has been created to increase productivity. If your way help to you increase productivity, then it does not matter how to another humans use this tool.

BUT

Generally, developers use one Vagrantfile per project and it under version control system like for example git

https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/index.html#for-developers

> Vagrant will isolate dependencies and their configuration within a single disposable, consistent environment

Different projects can require different environments. Project environment evaluated during project life-circle. It is more easier to maintain and use one Vagrantfile per project.